# How to reverse sound tracks from command-line?

Tags: windows, audio

How can I turn a normal sound track into a reversed file (play normal file as backward) from Command-line in windows platform? (using free and portable utilities)

Comment: Need a program = http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
Need help with a program = http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sox ( http://sox.sourceforge.net/ ) can do this. Sox is a cross platform audio tool.

1. Download, and install Sox
   [image: output]
2. Type in command prompt:

   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-1\sox.exe" -V "B:\track.wav" "B:\reversetrack.wav" reverse

You will need to substitute the Sox.exe path for the path of your sox installation (the one I used is default), and you can change `reversetrack.wav` to the filename you want.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553448/encode-video-in-reverse

PS: The War by Angels & Airwaves sounds really good in reverse.

Comment: Thank you. this was what I wanted. I'll check this answer as "Accepted" as son as I arrive home. but there is another question, how can I make it portable? because I want to keep it in my portable device so I can use it without installing. and thanks again. :)

Comment: @tootip Just download the .zip of Sox instead of the .exe. Extract it to your portable device, and run it from there (no installation process required). The exe version is just a self-extracting archive. Sox is a just-run program ( http://paste.ubuntu.com/8597346/ )